# In amsmath package, problems with TiKZ, \multicols & \enumitem

Tags: amsmath, tikz-arrows, multicol, enumitem

I'm trying to create a 3 cols vertically enumerated (1. 2. 3.) worksheet for my students to learn the distributive property.

h/t @peter grill and @tarass for the TiKz code that draws arrows to illustrate the distributions.

Problem:

log errors noting problems with
(a) enumeration
(b) multicols  and
(c) the problem solution steps don't align properly to the problem number.

Maybe a conflict with TiKz?

Thanks in advance for your help!

mwe:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand{\DrawBox}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[->,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt,out=70,in=130,distance=0.5cm,#1] (MarkA.north) to (MarkC.north);
    \draw[->,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt,out=50,in=140,distance=0.3cm,#2] (MarkA.north) to (MarkB.north);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
    \newlength{\MyL}

\newcommand{\TkM}[2]{%
    \settowidth{\MyL}{#2}
    #2\hspace{-\MyL}\makebox[\MyL]{\tikzmark{#1}}
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    
\[\TkM{MarkA}{a}(\TkM{MarkB}{b}+\TkM{MarkC}{c})=ab+ac
\DrawBox{OrangeRed,distance=0.45cm,in=130,shorten >=3pt,shorten <=3pt}{Cerulean,out=65,in=110,distance=0.3cm,shorten >=3.5pt,shorten <=3pt}\]

\begin{align*}
-(2x+5)&=(\TkM{MarkA}{-1})(\TkM{MarkB}{2x}+\TkM{MarkC}{5})
\DrawBox{OrangeRed,distance=0.6cm}{Cerulean,out=60,in=110,distance=0.4cm}\\
       &=(-1)(2x)+(-1)(5)\\
       &=-2x+(-5)\\
       &=-2x-5
\end{align*}

\end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I interchange positions of `\end{multicols}\end{enumerate}` to `\end{enumerate}\end{multicols}`, then compilation of your MWE doesn't throw errors. Only few warning like Overfull \hbox (16.51224pt too wide) detected ...`. But it is not entirely clear, what result you expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{enumerate} on input line 26 ended by \end{multicols}.
```

Because you have as it says `\begin{enumerate}` ending `\end{multicols}`

end the document

```
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

and you get no error.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the compiling errors! Can you also possibly fix the alignment issue, i.e. moving the expression and the solution steps to align with the problem number?